# Login base on user type (student & admin )

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to create a login that will redirect on different page base on its user type:

```php
<?php



session_start();
require_once "connection.php";

try {
   
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    

    if (isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $message = '<label>All filled are required</label>';
           
        }
        else
        {     
           
            $query = " SELECT * FROM main_user  WHERE username = :username AND password = :password " ;
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(
                array(
                    
                    'username' => $_POST["username"],
                    'password' => $_POST["password"]
                  
                )
            );


            $count =$stmt->rowCount();
             

            if($count > 0 )
            {

                
                 
                if( $count['user_type'] == 'admin'){

                $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                header("location:admin_portal.php");

                }
                else if( $count['user_type'] == 'student')
                {
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                    header("location:student_portal.php");                
                }


            }
            else
            {
                $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>';
            }

        }
    }


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage(); 
         
}

?>
```

My Database:

[image: My Database]

Comment: Storing user passwords in plain text is not recommended. You should use `password_hash` and `password_verify` when dealing with passwords

Comment: thank you sir I will Im still studying on how  to use password_hash

Answer (score 2):

1. First in Register form store Password with `password_hash()` function

```php
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

2. 2nd use below method for Login base on user type

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM main_user WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();

if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
    if ($user['user_type']=="admin") {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
        header("location:admin_portal.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
        header("location:student_portal.php"); 
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: thank you for sir! but my problem now  how am I going to put the isset condition  for login button?

Comment: In login form add button name <input type="submit" name="login">  and get it inside php with that name Like: if(isset($_POST['login'])){      }

Answer (score 0):

You are using the result of `PDOStatement::rowCount()` (which returns an integer) as the data:

```php
$count =$stmt->rowCount();
```

Use `PDOStatement::fetch()` to get the data:

```php
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($user['username'] == '...') {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow !! thank you sir it works  :) really appreciate

Comment: Just a note: you must hash your passwords with [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) during registration and use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) during login. Your app is insecure otherwise.